# Using jQuery.slideToggle() in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use jQuery's `slidetoggle()` function. Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#parent").click(function(){
        $("#child").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

It works perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox, though it has problems in IE. Normally, `slidetoggle()` toggles the css field display from `none` to `inline` and visa-versa. In IE, it seems that when `slideToggle()` is called, it toggles it `inline`, but a split second later, it turns display back to `none` (I'm guessing). It does it so quickly that it doesn't even display the text from the `div` `child`.

EDIT(1): I had the idea that IE may be "clicking" the parent an extra time, but after debugging, that wasn't the case.

EDIT(2): I tried using `jQuery.slideToggle()` in a place page (since the page I'm developing on is complex), and it works fine. I'm figuring that there is something that I have on that IE doesn't like. I'm still poking around trying to find the solution. Any hints and/or help would be appreciated.

FYI I'm using IE8.

Comment: Put a debug statement in the click handler to see if it even fires

Comment: I think I'm using 1.4.2 ( I know. I'm behind the curve)

Comment: @TGH I did. That's how I got the results from EDIT(1).

Comment: Unsure of the entire scenario, but have you tried stopping propagation? `$("#parent").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#child").slideToggle("slow");
});`